# Have done database attach upgrade to new domain test lab and users are getting "this site is not shared" error

Tags: claims

Our arch is that we are migrating to a new domain from a trusted domain.  The users new domain accounts are already in our site collections, but since we are moving from classic to claims, when the new site collections are put in the perms no longer work.

I need to upgrade the existing new domain creds to claims from classic.  How do I do that?

Comment: What form of trust is in between the domains?

Comment: The trust is full.  Our current set up has users with creds from the new domain since the migration of the computers has already happened.  I need to add the claims "characters" to the new domain login (i.e. domain/user now to i:0#.w|domain/user)  I was under the impression that  test-spcontentdatabase did the conversion, but on some of my test content dbs, it didn't work.  I tried some scripting to "convert" the db but that didn't work.  HELP!

Comment: `Convert-SPWebApplication -Identity http://webAppUrl -From Legacy -To Claims -RetainPermissoins:$true` is the cmdlet for SharePoint 2013 SP1+. You can rerun that every time you add a content db to the Web App. You say the trust is full, and by that you mean two-way? Regardless if it is two-way or not, you still need to put in the People Picker properties to search both domains. You just don't need to add an app password like you would with a one-way trust.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run this command as Trevor points out above.

```
Convert-SPWebApplication -Identity http://yourWebApplication -To Claims -From Legacy -RetainPermissions -Force
```

Also when migrating the databases it is important to test for errors first before running the mount command:

```
Test-SPContentDatabase -Name WSS_yourWebApplicationContentDB -WebApplication  http://yourWebApplication
Mount-SPContentDatabase -Name WSS_yourWebApplicationContentDB -WebApplication  http://yourWebApplication
```

Otherwise the only account that will end up getting access is your farm admin account in SP 2010 AD was the default Web Application Authentication, in 2013 MS switched to Claims Authentication as the default for Web Applications (This is how I recognized the issue when I was migrating from 2010 to 2013 the first time).

Happy SharePoint-ing!